# ListView / List Filter Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, list, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a list of data

```
public class PopImage
{
    public async Task<List<PopImage>> PopDatas()
    {
        string imgfolder = "PopularImages";
        var data = new List<PopImage>();
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFolder subfolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync(imgfolder);

        var files = await subfolder.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var items in files)
        {
            data.Add(new PopImage(imgfolder+"/"+items.DisplayName+ ".jpg", items.DisplayName));
        }

        return data;
    }

    public PopImage(string imagePath, string imageName)
    {
        ImagePath = imagePath;
        ImageName = imageName;
    }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add a textbox and filter it if textbox textchanged,
what do I need to apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a TextChanged event to your TextBox.
First in your XAML add this:

```
<TextBox Name="tbListFilter" TextChanged="tbListFilter_TextChanged"/>
```

Then the code behind is:

```
private void tbListFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     yourFilteredList = yourPopImageList.Where(p => p.ImageName.ToUpper().Contains(tbListFilter.Text.ToUpper())).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately in my case I can't implement it 100%
so I made a view changes,I will add it to my answer. Thanks again it really helps.

Comment: Oh I see your changes. But why can't you apply the LINQ version?

Comment: I got red squigly line : string does not contain definition for 'Contains', I have no idea shat happened.

Comment: Cool it works!
What do I missed?
what is the difference?

Comment: The problem was that in the previous version I used an extension method so my Contains method had two parameters. The second parameter indicated case insesitivity. Than could you please accept my answer?

Comment: ah I see, I already accepted your answer since the beginning :)
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Based on @WPMed

I try to make a new list from filtered items

```
var FilteredList= new List<PopImage>();
        foreach (var data in popimagelist)
        {
            if(data.ImageName.ToUpper().Contains(FilterText.Text.ToUpper()))FilteredList.Add(data);
        }
```

Thank you for the help