# How to add search in longlistselector windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a longlistselector control with data populated and also a textbox and on the TextChanged event of Textbox. I want to Filter the Longlist Selector and want to display only the Result according to search keyword in textbox.

Please help me how to do this.

Comment: On text changed event, repopulate the list using the input text as criteria.

Comment: search and change data in your viewmodel

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441433/listview-list-filter-windows-phone-8-1-c-sharp/29446100#29446100

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to use a CollectionView's filter. Here's a WinRT example which you can use on Windows Phone 8.1: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So And an example for Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight (where the .Filter is implemented by default): http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2012/04/12/Filtering-collections-from-XAML-using-CollectionViewSource.aspx